# How to Rename AspNetUsers table for a class inherited from IdentityUser in ASP .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I'm using ASP .NET Core 2.1 for my project with IndividualAuthentication.  I need extra properties for my User table so i inherited from `IdentityUser` like below :

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

After this modification `AspNetUsers` table is not renamed. All other identity tables are renamed. I don't know why is this happening.

After creating `ApplicationUser` class i have replaced `IdentityUser` with `ApplicationUser` in my code of `Startup.cs`

Below is the code before Modification

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

After modification

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

This is my OnModelCreating method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
        //modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>().ToTable("RoleClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>().ToTable("UserToken");
    }
```

Now i don't know what other thing i am missing for renaming `AspNetUsers` table. I didn't find any solution and still searching.

Comment: Most likely you are not using the correct base generic `IdentityDbContext`. Can we see it, e.g. `class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<…>`?

Comment: `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fluent configuration is ok, but the identity class used as base for your context is not.

As explained in the [Customizing the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize_identity_model?view=aspnetcore-2.1#customizing-the-model)
 (emphasis is mine):

> The starting point for customizing the model is **to derive from the appropriate context type**; see the preceding section.

and the preceding sections explain the base classes, generic type arguments and the default configuration.

With that being said, since you are using only a custom `IdentityUser` derived class, the base at least should be the `IdentityDbContext<TUser>`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks just found exactly same solution as you described and it solved my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you please answer this question also? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50785009/how-to-seed-an-admin-user-in-ef-core-2-1-0

Comment: I wish I could. Unfortunately my experience is mainly with EF Core. All I can say is that from EF Core point of view the posted answer looks correct. But not sure if it fits in the identity infrastructure.

Comment: just to add to the answer, I found microsoft docs very elaborate. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.1#change-tablecolumn-names-and-facets