# EF Core Seeding User Role Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have managed to seed the admin's details like the username and password, so they appear in the table. However, the issue I am having is the role "admin" is not being saved anywhere in the table. Am I missing something here? I am new to asp.net core so I'm just trying to wrap my head around it.

Below is my seeding class:

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer
{
    public static void SeedUsers(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        if (userManager.FindByEmailAsync("abc@outlook.com").Result == null)
        {
            IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
            {
                UserName = "abc@outlook.com",
                Email = "abc@outlook.com"
            };

            IdentityResult result = userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Passwordtest123!").Result;

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin").Wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my configure method signature:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
```

Below is me invoking my seed method:

```
ApplicationDbInitializer.SeedUsers(userManager);
```

Below is my add identity:

```
    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<RestaurantWebContext>();
```

Is there something in the code that is missing, I can't see admin show up in the role table or the user table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to seed the `Roles` as well, then link the User to the Role you want.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51571555/10816950) for more information of how you can seed the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can view my full code [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/Modules/AwesomeCMSCore.Modules.Entities/Data/SeedData.cs)

Below is an example

```
var user = new User
{
    Id = new Guid("a1add451-7dd2-46fd-9877-1996e3f1fb4c").ToString(),
    Email = "",
    NormalizedEmail = "".ToUpper(),
    UserName = "",
    NormalizedUserName = "tony5".ToUpper(),
    EmailConfirmed = true,
    PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
    LockoutEnabled = false,
    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
};

using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(
    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>()))
{
    var roles = new[]
        {"Owner", "Administrator", "Editor", "ContentWriter"};

    var roles1 = new[]
        {"Administrator"};

    var roles2 = new[]
        {"Editor"};

    var roles4 = new[]
        {"Owner", "Administrator"};

    if (!context.Roles.Any())
    {
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context);

            await roleStore.CreateAsync(new ApplicationRole
            {
                Name = role,
                NormalizedName = role.ToUpper()
            });
        }
    }

    if (!context.Users.Any())
    {
        await SeedUser(user, context, serviceProvider, roles4);
    }
}


private static async Task SeedUser(
    User user, 
    ApplicationDbContext context, 
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
    string[] roles)
{
    var password = new PasswordHasher<User>();
    var hashed = password.HashPassword(user, "123456");
    user.PasswordHash = hashed;
    var userStore = new UserStore<User>(context);

    await userStore.CreateAsync(user);
    await EnsureRole(serviceProvider, user.Email, roles);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```